# C# Reading text file, zipping in memory, storing to SQL Db when retrieved it had junk characters at the beginning and end

Tags: c#, .net

I am storing a Zipped file in a sql Db. My problem is that my output file has junk at the beginning ' ÿÿÿÿ  à ' and a '' at the end.
Perhaps an encoding problem?  I am unsure what to do about it.  Below is my code perhaps you are able to correct it?

Here is the file output from the database after decompressing and sending to notepad:

> ÿÿÿÿ          à  RQHR~OOPBILL~P ~P-WDM~11/06/2018~A0000000000    ~HE,NE            ~17/06/1970 ~F   ~P8111235 ~AITO, HARMONIE  ~GLUFA~LABEL~A1CHB~PRENA~LIPID~TSHFU~FRT4 ~U/A  ~MA/C ~EGFR1~UMICU~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~eol
>   RQHR~OOPBILL~C1~NIPMC~13/06/2018~A1111111111    ~ZEN,DA         ~04/04/1928 ~M   ~P8132387 ~EKE, NKEMAKOLAM ~A1CHB~LABEL~MA/C ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~     ~eol

I am unsure if the unexpected characters are coming in on the read or appearing on the output.  I have read about the 'BOM' perhaps this is related?

Here is my input code:

```
byte[] compressedFile=null;
Int64 FileSize;

// Save the orig text file into the Db
if (bSaveFile)
{
    Encoding utf8WithoutBom = new UTF8Encoding(false);
    byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
    FileSize = data.Length;

    byte[] compressedData =Util.Compress(data);

    compressedFile = compressedData;
}
```

CompressedFile is then stored into the database.

Here is my reading code:

```
public string OpenFile(string FileGUID)
{
    logger.Trace("Entered");

    Byte[] data = new byte[0] ;
    System.Data.DataTable oDt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    string Sql = "Select RefFile FROM FileDetails Where FileGID = '" + FileGUID + "'";

    SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, _SqlConnection);
    Da.Fill(oDt);
    if (oDt.Rows.Count > 0)
        data = (Byte[]) ( oDt.Rows[0]["RefFile"]);

    data = Util.Decompress(data);
    string tPath =  System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();

    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(tPath, 2048, FileOptions.None))
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(fs, data);
    }
    return tPath;
}
```

These are the compression routines it uses:

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    using (var gzip = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        gzip.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        gzip.Close();
    }
    return output.ToArray();
}

public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    var input = new MemoryStream();
    input.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    input.Position = 0;

    using (var gzip = new GZipStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
    {
        var buff = new byte[64];
        var read = gzip.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);

        while (read > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buff, 0, read);
            read = gzip.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            }
        gzip.Close();
    }
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Aside from CodeCaster's answer which should address the question as asked, you might want to consider re-writing your code to use streams throughout - including [to/from SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support). And eliminate the `MemoryStream`s as well - get out of the business of manually copying buffers around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this code:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(tPath, 2048, FileOptions.None))
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(fs, data);
}
```

The `BinaryFormatter` adds serialization metadata. Replace all this code with:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(tPath, data);
```